# Can't use with import in Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

When I import torch, there's a problem like this:

[image]

```
C: lUsers / ruiha Desktopl flappy_DQL>python flappy.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "flappy.py", line 2, in <module>
import torch
File "C: IUsers I rui ha /AppDat a / Local Programs I Python/ Python37 libIsite-packagesI torchl__init__.py", line 81, in <mod
ctypes.CDLL(dll)
File "C: LUsersI ruiha lAppDat a l Local | Programs I Python/ Python37 liblctypesl__init_.py", line 364, in _init_
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Comment: Do you have multiple python versions installed?

Comment: @Raveesh i dont have multiple versions,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you doing your development? I ask because I see that you are on Windows, where it is much more difficult to manage dll files (compared to Linux). Thus, I would avoid setting up your own bare environment (it would require debugging your OS) and use Anaconda, a Python manager with a focus on scientific computing. Install Anaconda, setup an environment (this is a 'virtual' environment managed by Anaconda), and you will be ready. Simply install torch by

`conda install PyTorch -c PyTorch`

You can then continue writing your ML app on Jupyter, terminal, etc. by using the Conda runtime to execute your file.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a very common problem when you have multiple versions of pythons. It is recommended to use a virtual environment to avoid this:

```
python3 -m venv pytorch-env
pytorch-env\Scripts\activate.bat
...
pip install ...

python flappy.py
```

See more information at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html. 
Good luck!